# Angular 8 input type date remove wrong date values

Tags: html, date, input

in my angular app, I have some input type date, for which I would like to remove wrong date formats, especially months without 31 days ( because input controls allow days until 31), such as 31/04/2020, 31/06/2020 ...

```
<label for="2-ddd" class="sr-only">Date de
                              début</label><input type="date" class="form-control" id="2-ddd"
                              placeholder="Date de début" formControlName="dtDebut" #dtDebut
                              [ngClass]=" {'is-invalid': submitted && f.dtDebut.errors && notFocused}" min="1900-01-01"
                              max="2099-12-31"  (input)="dateDebut($event.target.value)">
```

Have I to include a custom date Pipe ? Or is there a function in "input" to correct this problem ?

Comment: what is your input date format ?

Comment: my input date format is the following "dd/MM/yyyy" ( French Format),